# Can I add a complex handlebar expression?

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js, sendgrid

I'm trying to create a dynamic template in SendGrid. I have a handlebar for storeName from my app.
{{ storeName }}

Now there are more than a 100 stores under 4 different banners (eg. Real One, Low Beam, Monte and Huskar Promo) and the StoreName are unique with the banner name and store number (eg. Real One - 2010, Real One - 2222, Monte - 1524).

Each banner has a logo. I do not have a handlebar for the logo. So I decided to use a conditional handlebar expression to put the logo on the template depending on the storeName. It's too heavy and impractical to put 100 expressions for logos in a template.

I used something like this.

```
{{#equals StoreName "Real One - 2010"}}
logo.png
{{else}}{{{{#equals StoreName "Monte - 1524"}}
logo2.png
{{/equals}}{{/equals}}
```

Is there a way to use the 'include' to match at least one word on the storeName String in the handlebar so I just have to use 4 conditional expressions to achieve this? Or any other way?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could write a [custom Handlebars helper](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/#custom-helpers) to test whether some strings contains another string. As it looks like you are looking for a substring at the start of your target string, I will give an example of a `startsWith` custom helper:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('startsWith', function (full, part, options) {
    if (full.startsWith(part)) {
        return options.fn(this);
    }
    return options.inverse(this);
});
```

Your template syntax is a little off. You would need to include the helper call within the `else`'s mustache, as in:

```
{{#startsWith StoreName 'Real One'}}
    Real One logo
{{else startsWith StoreName 'Monte'}}
    Monte logo
{{/startsWith}}
```

I have created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/76484/qjvebfrs/) for reference.

Comment: Where does the JS reside if using a template in the template editor?

Comment: @IanHoar: It may not be possible to create custom helpers using a template editor.

Comment: I think you are correct, I can't find any info on it.